# JavaScript onClick hide and display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

**Solution Required**

At first display ***formOne*** only and when the button or menu is selected, hide the ***formOne*** and display ***formTwo***.
If the user selects again then display ***formOne*** and hide ***formTwo***.

**Error**

I am trying to display two form on the same page . There are two forms displayed, as ***formOne*** and ***formTwo***.

Now it displays both the form and hide only formOne.

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jQuery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".formOne").toggle();
        $(".formTwo").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Muktinath</button>

<form class="formOne"><input type="text" placeholder="Muktinath"/> </form>

<button>Manakamana</button>

<form class="formTwo"><input type="hidden" placeholder="Manakamana"/> </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, why don't you just toggle a class? `$(".formOne, .formTwo").toggleClass('hidden');` with `<form class="formTwo hidden">` and `.hidden { display: none;}`. And of course, the input inside `.formTwo` being of type text, not hidden...

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mp6oquxz/2/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith it works perfectly fine. But when I click on Muktinath button for two times, then it displays Manakamana at first and again displays muktinath. 
Is there any process where I can display Muktinath button to display mutinath form only and manakamana button for manakamana form only.

Comment: @sandeshphuyal like this https://jsfiddle.net/mp6oquxz/5/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith in this case it displayed only one button. How can I display both the button Manakamana and Muktinath , as well as muktinath form at first. When muktinath is clicked display muktinath form only and for manakamanaa button display manakamana form only not muktinath form !!

Comment: @sandeshphuyal like this? I switched the form names so it is less confusing for me  https://jsfiddle.net/mp6oquxz/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE

Using the `,show()` and `.hide()` methods are another possibility. All details are in the Snippet

#### SNIPPET 2

```css
#formTwo { display: none; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button").click(function(e){
          
          /*
          Get the clicked button's form value
          */// ex. 'formOne'
          
          var formID = this.getAttribute('form');
          
          /*
          Concat the srting formID with a '#' then wrap it up as a jQObject
          */// ex. $('#formOne')
          
          var target = $('#'+formID);
          
          var other = $('form').not(target);
          /*
          seen and unseen states will be determined on 'this'
          */
          
          var seen = target.is(":visible"); 
          
          var unseen = target.is(":hidden");
          
          /*
          Ternary conditional to determine status of 'this',
          then invoke the opposite status.
          */

          var status = (seen) ?  reveal() : obscure();

          function reveal() { 
            target.hide();
            other.show();
          }
          
          function  obscure() {
             other.hide();
             target.show();
          }
          
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--Added form attribute to each button-->
      
    <button form="formOne">Muktinath</button><button form="formTwo">Manakamana</button>
     
    <!--Changed each form class to id-->
      
    <form id="formOne"><input type="text" placeholder="Muktinath"/> </form>


    <form id="formTwo"><input type="text" placeholder="Manakamana"/> </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Used `toggleClass()` and made two classes `.hide` and `.show`

```css
.hide { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(e){

        $(".formOne").toggleClass('show hide');
        $(".formTwo").toggleClass('show hide');
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Muktinath</button><button>Manakamana</button>

<form class="formOne hide"><input type="text" placeholder="Muktinath"/> </form>



<form class="formTwo show"><input type="text" placeholder="Manakamana"/> </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: onClick works on both muktinath and manakamana . Is there any process where I can define muktinath button to display muktinath form only and manakamana button to display manakamana form only.

Comment: Sure is, did you want it on the condition only one button and form exists at any given time?

Comment: displaying one form at first as well as both the button Muktinath and Manakama. When the muktinath is clicked display muktinath form only and hide manakamana form. When the user selects manakamana display manakamana form only.

Comment: Ready for review, sir.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE FOR COMMENTS BELOW QUESTION**

To add the buttons inside the the form, use `<input type="button" />` so the button press will not submit the form, and put the button inside the form itself so that it will toggle together.

Jquery

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(".formTwo").toggle();
    $("input[type=button]").click(function(){
        $(".formOne").toggle();
        $(".formTwo").toggle();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
  <form class="formOne">
    <input type="button" value="Muktinath" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Muktinath" />
  </form>

  <form class="formTwo">
    <input type="button" value="Manakamana" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Manakamana" />
  </form>
```

**old answer**

remove the `$(".formTwo").show();` since it will always show `.formTwo` on button click.

You want to toggle them, use `$(".formOne, .formTwo").toggle();` instead, also since you do not want `.formTwo` to show on page load add a `toggle()` after document ready and before button click, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".formTwo").toggle();
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".formOne, .formTwo").toggle();
    });
});
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/mp6oquxz/4/